# Template item in simple SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint

We don't do any SharePoint development, but I was wondering if there's a way in the web UI to create the ability to copy an existing list item as if it were a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to do that without at least some code or using SharePoint Designer.  In code it is fairly simple to do, but I don't think this is what you are asking for.

You could switch to datasheet view and then use copy & paste, but that isn't really a great solution either.

You could use a SharePoint Designer workflow to create duplicates of an item through the WebUI, there is an example of this [here](http://www.articlesbase.com/software-articles/how-do-i-duplicate-a-list-item-without-code-1042658.html).

Answer (score 0):

We have this capability as part of our product. The product is called Smart List Lite, it is free and it also install a new custom field type called Item Copy Field, I think this is what you need
http://www.infowisesolutions.com